# Clip can play mp3 but OpenAL just gives silence (Java)

Tags: java, audio, mp3, openal, audioinputstream

When I test an mp3 file using sound.sampled.Clip, it plays just as expected. When I test it with OpenAL however, I get **no sound, and no exception**.

(I'm using JMF's mp3plugin.jar as well as the OpenAL libraries)

This is a difficult problem to demonstrate with simple code, since working with openal requires a number of libraries and a bit of setup code, however I've tried my best:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    init(); //initialises OpenAL's device, context and alCapabilities

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    System.out.println("Clip");

    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("grumble.mp3"));
    ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, ais);        
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(ais);
    clip.start(); //plays both wav and mp3

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    clip.close();
    ais.close();
    System.out.println("OpenAL");

    ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("grumble.mp3"));
    ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, ais);
    AudioFormat format = ais.getFormat();
    byte[] byteArr = new byte[ais.available()];
    ais.read(byteArr);

    ByteBuffer buf = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(byteArr.length);
    buf.put(byteArr);
    byteArr = null;
    ais.close();
    buf.flip();

    int buffer = alGenBuffers();
    alBufferData(buffer, getALFormat(format), buf, (int)format.getSampleRate() );
    int source = alGenSources();
    alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, buffer);

    alSourcePlay(source); //plays wav, but is silent when trying to play mp3

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    System.out.println("end");
    alDeleteSources(source);
    alcCloseDevice(device);
}

public static int getALFormat(AudioFormat format)
{
    int alFormat = -1;
    if (format.getChannels() == 1) {
        System.out.println("mono ");
        if (format.getSampleSizeInBits() == 8) {
            alFormat = AL_FORMAT_MONO8;
        } else if (format.getSampleSizeInBits() == 16) {
            alFormat = AL_FORMAT_MONO16;
        } else {
            System.out.println("sample size: "+format.getSampleSizeInBits());
        }
    } else if (format.getChannels() == 2) {
        System.out.println("stereo ");
        if (format.getSampleSizeInBits() == 8) {
            alFormat = AL_FORMAT_STEREO8;
        } else if (format.getSampleSizeInBits() == 16) {
            alFormat = AL_FORMAT_STEREO16;
        } else {
            System.out.println("sample size: "+format.getSampleSizeInBits());
        }
    }

    return alFormat;
}
```

and this is all I get in console:

```
Clip
OpenAL
stereo 
end
```

In-case you're wondering why I need to use OpenAL, OpenAL provides both panning and pitch manipulation that Clip is a lot more touchy with. I have been able to pan and pitch any wav file I give it, whereas Clip frequently won't do either (and has latency when adjusting panning/gain, whereas OpenAL is instant).

Comment: The lightweight https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue is maybe an alternative that would work for you. It provides real time volume, panning and pitch controls. It is built on top of javax.audio.sampled.SourceDataLine.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner I am trying to avoid complications with licensing; I'd rather find a solution using OpenAL if possible, unless there's a big reason to go with AudioCue instead of OpenAL?

Comment: Well, I should disclose that I wrote it and am happy to see people make use of it. The license is one of the least restrictive I could find. The code is easy to inspect, and fully documented. Feel free to examine how things are done, and use ideas. Real-time changes happen on a per-audio-frame basis. I don't have all of 3D features of OpenAL implemented, like reverb or filters. When I took a look at OpenAL, I was a bit dismayed with some complications in how audio path is routed. But it is powerful and if you get it to work, great! Just letting you know about an easy, powerful alternative.

Comment: And your AudioCue can play mp3? Or simply requires the plugin to work? Also, is it platform-independent?

Comment: It will run on any platform that Java runs on. It only uses core java. The main hitch will be decoding the mp3 files. If you can decode an mp3 data into a float array, with data points ranging -1 to 1, that array can be used as source data for the AudioCue. I think there are libraries available for this, e.g., https://github.com/goxr3plus/java-sound-libraries

Comment: Won't run on Android. If your mp3's are very long and require streaming, can't be held in memory, then that will be problematic for AudioCue. I managed to write a dubious mod to the Jorbis library to decode ogg/vorbis cues into Clip-sized AudioCues.(Can show you what I did but code needs improvements.) Am assuming same can be done with mp3 libraries with code exposed. But never bothered as ogg/vorbis is arguably better than mp3.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer as to why Clip is able to play mp3 while OpenAL is not. I have the mp3 plugin, and there are no exceptions.

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't gotten any help with this. Perhaps test the OpenAL code with Ogg/vorbis instead of mp3? (It does work for you with .wav files, yes?) If it works with ogg/vorbis, Audacity (free) can be used to make the ogg files. I understand a bit about the JOrbis library and might be able to help with connecting to the little I know about OpenAL but have never looked at the mp3 decoder. java-gaming.org has an Audio forum, and some of members are authors of libgdx, maybe they can help you there.

Comment: Just looked up the jmf mp3plugin. That is old tech! That could be part of why you are not getting any traction. You might have better luck trying the mp3 libraries that I linked above (goxr3plus). At least with them (also old), you have actual source code to examine in trying to solve this.